# Sending Serial Hex Command from Pin 1 (Tx)

Tags: arduino-uno, serial, programming, sketch

Using Arduino Uno with 3.5mm Jack connected to ground and pin 1 for TX

Need to send two commands
I want to send 
0XAA13FE010113 for Mute on, and 
0XAA13FE010012 for Mute off.

Simple Serial Command to turn Monitor Mute on and off every 5 seconds....

tried everything byte character, array, write with hex, print :(

Thx for a helping a rookie 
I want to impress my team

---

Ideal quick answer below. thx to @martynas

```
uint8_t muteON[] = { 0xAA, 0x13, 0xFE, 0x01, 0x01, 0x13 };
uint8_t muteOFF[] = { 0xAA, 0x13, 0xFE, 0x01, 0x00, 0x12 };
.... 
void loop() {
 Serial.write( muteON, sizeof(muteON) );  
 delay(5000);               // wait for 5 second
 Serial.write( muteOFF, sizeof(muteOFF) );
 delay(5000);               // wait for 5 second
}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Don't expect people here to do EVERYTHING for you! How would you "impress your team" with something other people would have completely done for you?

Comment: Please add some code to your question so we can help debug it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are 6 bytes just make

```
byte muteON[] = {0xAA,0x13,0xFE,0x01,0x01,0x13};
byte muteOFF[] = {0XAA,0x13,0xFE,0x01,0x00,0x12};
...
/* To send mute ON comand */
for(byte i =0;i<sizeof(muteON);i++)(Serial.write(muteON[i]));
/* To send mute OFF comand */
for(byte i =0;i<sizeof(muteOFF);i++)(Serial.write(muteOFF[i]));
```

Comment: I do not know you, your programming level etc. Wrote as clear as i could

Comment: So is it working?

Comment: Also you can use `SoftwareSerial`. Then you can choose Tx pin

Comment: I am using Arduino uno.
when setting   Serial.begin(9600);
does that send serial output via usb and pin 1?

Comment: No you just set the output baud rate.